# Unable to install OSM Editor on ArcGIS 10.2.0?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, openstreetmap, arcgis-editor-osm

Esri have provided installers of the ArcGIS Editor for OpenStreetMap for 10.2.1 and 10.2.2, but not for 10.2.

How can I make it?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.

Answer (score 2):

This is explained on the download page of the [ArcGIS Editor for OSM, 10.2.x Desktop](http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=16970017f81349548d0a9eead0ebba39):

> Also, there is not an installer for ArcGIS Desktop 10.2.0 because at
>   the 10.2.1 update, significant changes to this toolbox were made that
>   were not backported to 10.2.

I recommend installing a later version of ArcGIS for Desktop, taking care to choose one for which an ArcGIS Editor for OSM installer is available.

Comment: Yeah I have noticed that.But I just want to know if there is a way that needn't reinstall my arcgis desktop. Seems not.Thanks anyway.